# Make a UDP Request to a Remote URL

Tags: node.js

I'd like to send messages to a UDP socket, I was googling about `http.request` but I just realized it only uses on the `http` protocol (or is it?). How can I make UDP requests in node.js? I'm from PHP and I previously just use `fsockopen`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html

anything HTTP will always be TCP because HTTP relies on guaranteed message delivery.